# Stop the timer when get the string

Tags: android, eclipse

I want to make a Timer app that counting how long someone typing.

I want to perform the following steps-

1. Start a timer when the EditBox is clicked and typing is started
2. On clicking a button the text is shown in the TextView
3. The timer stops as soon as I retrieve the value from the TextView after the button click at  Step 2

Comment: Add What you have tried and where you stuck?

Comment: what's the use of timer functionality?

Comment: @athira maybe you can check my project 

https://drive.google.com/open?id=178jcriLXa4UXcuWO3D5R_hZrocx7WZhU

Comment: @vivekMishra  On clicking a button the text is shown in the TextView

The timer stops as soon as I retrieve the value from the TextView after the button 

I still need it when the I retrieve the value from the TextView not the edit Text.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `TextWatcher` for this purpose. `TextWatcher’s`  `afterTextChanged()` method is called to notify you that, somewhere within `EditText`, the text has been changed.

If a text is changed and length is 1 that means typing is started, length is 0 means typing is stopped.

Sample android code:

```
messageEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

      if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s.toString()) && s.toString().trim().length() == 1) {

          //Log.i(TAG, “typing started event…”);

          typingStarted = true;

           //send typing started status

      } else if (s.toString().trim().length() == 0 && typingStarted) {

          //Log.i(TAG, “typing stopped event…”);

          typingStarted = false;

           //send typing stopped status
     }
}

});
```

You can start & stop your timer based on values above.